# I cant get my absolute position to find the relate positioned parent

Tags: html, css, absolute

I placed my absolute positioned element inside a div with a relative position, but it won't seem to recognize it as parent.

```css
#picture {
  position: relative;
  top: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../images/homepage.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#picturecredit {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  color: grey;
  padding-right: 8px;
  font-size: 11;
}
```

```html
<div id="picture">
  <div id="picturecredit">
    <p> Foto: Name </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Also, `font-size: 11;` needs a unit.

Comment: It works correctly to me but I have no clue what is "correct" for you.

Comment: I want the picture credit, to be placed in the bottom right corner of the picture, but the credit uses the document as parent, not the picture.

Comment: It is because you height 100% does nothing of your relative element :)

Comment: Yes, change your height to something in pixels, or fill the div with an image or something, and it will work the way you expect. Try just doing height: 100px;  You'll see it works the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of the relative `#picture` so it doesn't default to `0px`.

```css
#picture {
  position: relative;
  top: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(../images/homepage.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#picturecredit {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  color: grey;
  padding-right: 8px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div id="picture">
  <div id="picturecredit">
    <p> Foto: Name </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `height` of the relative div, it needs an explicit unit (px, in, rem). Also, as j08691 said, don't forget to set a css unit to font-size property in `#picturecredit` (it just has `11` of nothing).